# Disappearing bone shapes with rigify (show_wire)

Tags: scripting

In the transition of 2.79 to 2.8 there are currently still some problems. The main problem I'm having is, now I can't see my wire shapes without manually selecting "show wireframe" on all of my bones.
I know this is going to happen so I'd like to automate it.
Is there a simple script that can turn wireframe on or off on all selected pose bones?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script, simply hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when clicking the checkbox, it should do the action on the whole selection. Unless this function is broken in your 2.8 build of course x)

Comment: Holy jeez, you can do that with everything too? That's useful, thanks!

Comment: Almost everything, yes ;)
Don't forget to vote up if my answer did help you.